# Como otimizar a remoção de linhas em uma matriz?

Tags: r

Tenho uma matriz de dimensões:

```
> dim(filtro1)
[1] 2806519      31
```

Preciso remover as linhas dessa matriz que atendam um condição. Até aí tudo bem. Porém, computacionalmente o loop for para isso tem sido muito caro (demorado - 8 a 10 horas).
Já tentei rbind, mas esse é mais demorado que a solução abaixo:

```
for(i in 1:length(filtro1[,1])){
  if(filtro1[i,31] == 0){
    filtro1 <- filtro1[-i,]
    print(i)
  }
}
```

- o print(i) serve apenas para eu acompanhar a execução do loop

Tentei executar o código paralelamente com foreach e %dopar%, mas aparentemente ele não funciona, pois o raciocínio acima depende do índice

Alguém sabe como executar a remoção das linhas da matriz de maneira mais rápida e eficiente?

Comment: Além de demorado esse código não está certo. Assim que remove uma linha, `filtro1` deixa de ter `2806519` linhas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O R é uma linguagem vetorizada e a melhor forma de fazer isso seria algo do tipo:

```
filtro1 <- filtro1[filtro1[,31] != 0, ]
```

Acho que o melhor lugar para aprender sobre vetorização é o [capítulo 3 do R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).